# Pandas: How to sort rows based on particular suffix values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting

My Pandas data frame contains the following data reading from a csv file:

```
id,values
 1001-MAC,     10
 1034-WIN,     20
 2001-WIN,     15
 3001-MAC,     45
 4001-LINUX,   12
 4001-MAC,     67

df = pd.read_csv('example.csv')
df.set_index('id', inplace=True)
```

I have to sort this data frame based on the id column order by given suffix list = ["WIN", "MAC", "LINUX"]. Thus, I would like to get the following output:

```
 id,values
 1034-WIN,     20
 2001-WIN,     15
 1001-MAC,     10
 3001-MAC,     45
 4001-MAC,     67
 4001-LINUX,   12
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one way to do that:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('example.csv')
idx = df.id.str.split('-').str[1].sort_values(ascending=False).index

df = df.loc[idx]
df.set_index('id', inplace=True)
print(df)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```py
df = df.sort_values(
    by=["id"], key=lambda x: x.str.split("-").str[1], ascending=False
)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
           id  values
1    1034-WIN      20
2    2001-WIN      15
0    1001-MAC      10
3    3001-MAC      45
5    4001-MAC      67
4  4001-LINUX      12
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a column to a dataframe that would contain only prefixes (use str.split() function for that) and sort whole df based on that new column.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "id":["1001-MAC", "1034-WIN", "2001-WIN", "3001-MAC", "4001-LINUX", "4001-MAC"],
    "values":[10, 20, 15, 45, 12, 67]
})
df["id_postfix"] = df["id"].apply(lambda x: x.split("-")[1])
df = df.sort_values("id_postfix", ascending=False)
df = df[["id", "values"]]
print(df)
```

Answer (score 1):

[image]
Please be sure to answer the question. Provide details and share your research!